# How does the Particle Instance modifier work?

Tags: modifiers, particles

I'm trying to figure out the Particle Instance modifier and how it functions, but as yet have had little success. I'd greatly appreciate it if somebody could give me a rundown on its functions and how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This modifier allows FX but works **only** with another object that has a particle system.
An example:

1. Add a cube and give it a particle system with Hair,
2. Add a UV sphere and apply **particle instance** to it,
3. Now, in Particle Instance, select the  cube in the object field.
4. In Particle System experiment with hair length.

Try out all options.

Comment: I did all your steps, I still don't see how this works. Not being negative here but your instructions are really unclear. I think step 4 could have some more detail.